# Unable to filter values from array using .find()

Tags: javascript

I have a function that returns a value from a JSON file ⁠— this works fine.

```
$.get(url), function(result)
```

I have a list containing 3 values. If the value of `result` equals a value from this list then I want to add `result` to my page. I tried to accomplish this below, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {
     $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
         $("#postcode").html("Postcode: " + response.postal);
 }, "jsonp");
 var array1 = [  {name: 'Edinburgh', tno: '0131 111 2222'},
                 {name: 'Fife', tno: '01383 111222'},
                 {name: 'Glasgow', tno: '0141 111 2222'} ];
 if address = array1.find(function(found) {
   return found.tno;
 });
 window.alert(found);
 // expected output: Fife
 /* HTML =
 <div id="address"></div>
 <div id="postcode"></div>
 */
```

Comment: Your `if` syntax is wrong. You need parentheses around the condition, and you need to use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: `found` is a local variable inside the function, you can't use it after the function returns.

Comment: The callback function needs to compare `found.tno` with the phone number you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure what you expect that `find()` to do....will return the first item with a truthy `tno` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `array1.find()` correctly. The function needs to compare `found.tno` with the phone number you're searching for. Then you need to log the value that's returned, not `found`, which is a local variable in the callback function.

```js
function lookup_tno(tno) {
  var array1 = [{
      name: 'Edinburgh',
      tno: '0131 111 2222'
    },
    {
      name: 'Fife',
      tno: '01383 111222'
    },
    {
      name: 'Glasgow',
      tno: '0141 111 2222'
    }
  ];
  var address = array1.find(el => el.tno == tno);
  if (address) {
    return address.name;
  }
}
console.log(lookup_tno('01383 111222'));
```